# Rails installation can't find active_model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I created a fresh project using rails new Project -d=postgresql. If I then run rails server, I get the following error message:

```
C:/GemRepository/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch.rb:34:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_model (LoadError)
    from C:/GemRepository/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch.rb:34:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/GemRepository/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:3:in `require'
    from C:/GemRepository/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/GemRepository/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:48:in `require'
    from C:/GemRepository/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I also tried

```
gem which active_model
```

which returned

```
C:/GemRepository/gems/activemodel-3.1.1/lib/active_model.rb
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I managed to solve it.

I restarted my computer, deleted everything from my gem repository, reinstalled rubygems (ruby setup.rb) and reinstalled rails (gem install rails).

Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem, came across this post. This fixed it for me:

```
rvm gemset pristine
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of rails is in the gem file? And have you run 'bundle install'?

I notice that Actionpack is 3.1.3 is called by the server, but the activemodel found is 3.1.1.

Comment: The gem file declares rails 3.1.3. and yes, I have run both bundle install and bundle update many times.

Answer (score 0):

Run the `bundle` command from the project directory

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and it was due to accidentally corrupting my `Gemfile`, so it is worth checking that. If it is version controlled then just `git checkout Gemfile` and `bundle update` to rebuild.

Answer (score -1):

gem uninstall active-model and perfomr gem install active-model

Comment: there is no active-model, it should be activemodel, example of gem install activemodel. see this link - https://rubygems.org/gems/activemodel

Comment: Please describe what this does and how it addresses the problem.